# XOR hex ascii values of letters

Tags: java, math, cryptography

I'm trying to complete some homework and am totally stumped. The function I need to perform is, given the hexadecimal value of a character, xor it with another hex value to verify a known end value.

Giving a simple example (the one given to me), I know that the ascii value of 'Bob' would be [42,6F,62], and 'Eve' would be [45,76,65]. I have to XOR 'Bob''s value with [07,16,17] to get 'Eve'.

I thought that xor was simply addition modulo base, but simply using the Microsoft Calculator: (42 + 45) mod 16 = 3 but 42 XOR 45 = 7. I do not understand how else the XOR function would be done. Can someone please explain?

Thanks in advance

I tried

```
float l = (6F)^(16);
System.out.println(l);
```

and got this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - bad operand types for binary operator '^'
  first type:  float
  second type: double
    at p2p_example.P2P_Example.main(P2P_Example.java:40)
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XOR is a bitwise exclusive-or,

```
42 = 1000010
45 = 1000101
```

---

```
 7 = 0000111
```

That is a one if there is one (and only one) one in the two bits being XORd. For Java, you can use [parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) and pass in the radix, for example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = Integer.parseInt("42", 16);
    int b = Integer.parseInt("45", 16);
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(a ^ b, 16));
}
```

prints

```
7
```

Comment: So it is better to convert to binary to do XOR. I primarily use with Java, how would I use java to implement a binary (or hexadecimal) xor function? As far as I know, Java's number system only works with base 10

Comment: XOR is the same no matter what the base is. Numbers have the same value no matter how they're represented. There is no such thing as a "binary xor" function.

Comment: @yazan I edited my answer to include Java code; if you had tagged your question with Java in the first place I would have posted this earlier.

Comment: Int to int... where are you getting double and float from?

Comment: I dont know how to add line spaces in a comment. ill edit original post

Comment: So Integer.parseInt is what I would need. Thank you so much for adding the code

Answer (score 1):

```
0x42 + 0x45 = 0x87
            = 135

135 % 16 = 7 = 0x07
```

I think you're getting confused between hex and decimal bases (though (42+45)%16 also happens to be 7 in decimal; so maybe you're just doing your math wrong?)